# How to make the earthquake response spectrum graph

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

As far as I understand, there are two ways to make the earthquake response spectrum graph. One by experiment with a set of oscillators with different periods, to which we apply the earthquake's time vs acceleration shaking to get maximum responses, and the other method is by solving equation of motion for each period of the earthquake time vs acceleration record to get maximum responses. Am I correct? 
Then we convert this response spectrum into a smoothened design response spectrum, which is the actual one we use on our structure.
Am I correct?
If not, what am I missing here?

Comment: Plot values on the x axis against values on the y...

Comment: really? wow.... I didn't know.... how did you get this much reputation I wonder?

Comment: answering interesting questions helps...

Comment: This is interesting and useful question - for people who has even little bit of idea about the subject....

Comment: This is an interesting and useful question - for people who have even a little bit of an idea about the subject....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, except that even the part that is calculated is based on real ground motion accelerator graphs first published by George W. Housner in 1941 at Caltech.

Otherwise, they use SDOF diapasons like this.

[image: diapasoes]

-And here is the graph.

Wikipedia page [Link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_spectrum)

[image: graph]

Comment: I saw this on wikipedia too. This explains the one method I mention. Is solving by equation the equivalent of this? This is my question.

Comment: No it is not. You have to read the paragraph on Housner. He used accellerameter graphs. Are you familiar with those?

Comment: accelerometer graphs is the first of the two alternatives I mentioned in my post already. I am asking, is solving by equation of motion the equivalent of making experiment with oscillators. I already had looked at that page you gave, and went through other sources.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, may be you want to edit you question to better explain your concern.

Comment: I think it is clear. I am asking, if we indeed have two alternatives of doing this. One way is the one you posted, which I also stated as the first alternative. But from the sources I have been reading, I am also seeing that they are solving the dynamic equation of motion to come up with response spectrum, instead of using oscillators. I am trying to confirm if indeed these two things are equivalent to each other and means the same thing.

Comment: In other words, how the maximum responses are determined in the method above for example? It boils down to that. Do we determine the maximum responses in the method above by measuring with actual devices, or we calculate them by equation of motion,and there is no physical experiment going on, and the one above is just for illustration? If the latter is true, then there is only one thing we are doing - both things mean the same thing, and we are doing everything with equation, and not physical oscillators